# Text introducing $T^{i,j}$-tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, book-recommendation, tensors

I'm reading a lecture note here : http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/diffgeom7.pdf

It introduces $T^{•,•}(M)$ the tensor algebra and says that this is a necessary tool in differential geometry. Well, this is the first time I see this variant tensor algebra (I only know the tensor algebra by standard means) and there is almost no detail about this in the link. All there given is almost just the definition. Is there a  text introducing this variant tensor algebra **formally**?

Thank you in advance.

( To be clear, if $M$ is an $R$-modules where $R$ is a commutative ring, $T^{i,j}(M)$ is defined as the tensor product of $i$-times tensor product of $M$ and $j$-times tensor product of $M^*$. And $T^{•,•}(M)$ is defined as the direct sum of those with the natural operation that makes it an algebra)

Comment: Ok, I am not sure exactly which description of the tensor algebra you would like. There is a standard construction of say $V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W$, where $R$ is (say) a commutative ring, and $V$, $W$ are two $R$-modules. You consider the free $R$-module generated by the set $V \times W$, and then you quotient out by relations, which correspond to bilinearity. This shows the existence of the tensor product. Moreover, you can check that it has a universal property, so that it follows that it is unique up to isomorphism. I think you can find this in Lang's algebra, or in Atiyah and MacDonald.

Comment: You can then generalize this to the tensor product of more than two modules. The tensor algebra is indeed very important in differential geometry. Its "sections" are called tensors, and include vector fields, differential forms, two-forms with values in the endomorphism of the tangent bundle (such as the curvature of a metric), and more... What it does not include, is things like spinors, for instance, assuming the manifold is spin. But you should start by understanding tensors first, pedagogically speaking.